# About Eager Loading with select filter in Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a relation defined

```
class people {
    public function hobbies() {
        return $this->hasMany(hobby::class, "people_id")->select(['name', 'action', 'effect']);
    }
}
```

and I tried to load with eager loading

```
people::with('hobbies')->get();
```

end up my result for `hobbies` is always empty, then I find out it is because the select filter is without the `people_id` in the relation of `people` to `hobbies` like

```
public function hobbies() {
        return $this->hasMany(hobby::class, "people_id")->select(['people_id', 'name', 'action', 'effect']);
    }
```

Then I have a question now, why does it need the foreign key in select filter?

For a sql query, `select hobbies.name, hobbies.action, hobbies.effect from hobbies join people on hobbies.people _id = people.id` is enough to retrieve the data?

Comment: you might want to remove `select()` from your model and do it like this to be more dynamic `CDE::with('ABC:id,foo,bar')->get();` or even like this

```CDE::with(['ABC', function($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'foo', 'bar', 'created_at', 'whatever');
}])->get();```

Comment: you should always select your **relations key** column in relation models. if you don't select that so eloquent cant find related row.

Comment: Would be better if you replace `ABC, CDE` with your actual `model` names. It will be much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @اسماعیلزارع, no, since it is join from people, I already with people.id right? it is just easier access from hobbies for hobbies.people_id, it can be directly assign hobbies_people_id from people.id. In the people model, I using `get()`, so all data in people model is retrieved, for people model relational model, when the foreign key is empty, can check from people and grab it?

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand the reason I using select, just to retrieve lesser field from database. And for the 2nd method you writen `CDE::with(['ABC', function($query) { $query->select('id', 'foo', 'bar', 'created_at', 'whatever'); }])->get();`, I not sure this way, when the record is 25, it will be query for 26 times or not, since the proposal of eager loading is to minimize the process from 26 to 2.

Comment: @dexterb it is now renamed as my model name

Comment: @Yu Yenkan well you can install laravel debugbar provided by barryvdh and it shows you total queries and requests. I'm sure it doesnt add query and I'm sure that's the right and more dynamic way since I fully read laravel's relationships section so after all its all on you, my answer was just a suggestion that's all

Comment: thats wrong. youshould fetch relation key. if you not want them you can add that to hidden attribute by method **addHidden** @Yu Yenkan

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand thanks for suggestion, I will try it later

Comment: @اسماعیلزارع this may help, but this way is not very good, since the table may related from multiple like `hobbies` with `player_id` and 'material_id', when I fetch from material table, I need `player_id` and hide `material_id` now.

Answer (score 0):

The eager loading query actually looks like this:

```
select `people_id`, `name`, `action`, `effect`
from `hobbies`
where `people_id` in (1, 2, 3, ...)
```

If you remove `people_id` from the `SELECT` columns, Laravel doesn't know which people the hobbies belong to.

Comment: in the `$this->hasMany(hobby::class, "people_id")`, laravel already know I am using `people_id` as foreign key, so it does not needed on select.

Comment: That's not how it works. The whole point of eager loading is to get the hobbies for all people in one single query. Then Laravel assigns them to the right people by looking at the `people_id` value. It's impossible without it.